# Evaluating AWS RDS Proxy latency overhead

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, aws, pgbouncer

Evaluating some benchmark tests I noticed that there is latency overhead in the transactions to the database using the service provided by AWS: [RDS Proxy](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/proxy/).

The tests were performed against a Postgres RDS database running on a `db.m6i.large` instance and using the Proxy service in front of it.

The benchmark tool used was the [pgbench](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgbench.html) and the test was started from an instance in the same region and VPC as the Proxy and RDS.

Initialization: `pgbench -i -s 1000`

Execution parameters: `pgbench -c 600 -n -T 60 -P 1 -r`

Here is the test result connecting directly to the RDS instance:

```
transaction type: <builtin: TPC-B (sort of)>
scaling factor: 1000
query mode: simple
number of clients: 600
number of threads: 1
duration: 60 s
number of transactions actually processed: 63283
**latency average = 528.054 ms**
latency stddev = 92.859 ms
initial connection time = 3845.934 ms
tps = 1115.366761 (without initial connection time)
statement latencies in milliseconds:
         0.001  \set aid random(1, 100000 * :scale)
         0.000  \set bid random(1, 1 * :scale)
         0.000  \set tid random(1, 10 * :scale)
         0.000  \set delta random(-5000, 5000)
        85.201  BEGIN;
        95.344  UPDATE pgbench_accounts SET abalance = abalance + :delta WHERE aid = :aid;
        46.328  SELECT abalance FROM pgbench_accounts WHERE aid = :aid;
        75.641  UPDATE pgbench_tellers SET tbalance = tbalance + :delta WHERE tid = :tid;
        64.002  UPDATE pgbench_branches SET bbalance = bbalance + :delta WHERE bid = :bid;
        64.194  INSERT INTO pgbench_history (tid, bid, aid, delta, mtime) VALUES (:tid, :bid, :aid, :delta, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
        97.343  END;
```

And here is the test connecting to the RDS Proxy endpoint:

```
transaction type: <builtin: TPC-B (sort of)>
scaling factor: 1000
query mode: simple
number of clients: 600
number of threads: 1
duration: 60 s
number of transactions actually processed: 51649
**latency average = 553.454 ms**
latency stddev = 125.466 ms
initial connection time = 11986.807 ms
tps = 1064.153153 (without initial connection time)
statement latencies in milliseconds:
         0.001  \set aid random(1, 100000 * :scale)
         0.000  \set bid random(1, 1 * :scale)
         0.000  \set tid random(1, 10 * :scale)
         0.000  \set delta random(-5000, 5000)
        90.279  BEGIN;
        94.776  UPDATE pgbench_accounts SET abalance = abalance + :delta WHERE aid = :aid;
        54.753  SELECT abalance FROM pgbench_accounts WHERE aid = :aid;
        76.686  UPDATE pgbench_tellers SET tbalance = tbalance + :delta WHERE tid = :tid;
        72.362  UPDATE pgbench_branches SET bbalance = bbalance + :delta WHERE bid = :bid;
        66.628  INSERT INTO pgbench_history (tid, bid, aid, delta, mtime) VALUES (:tid, :bid, :aid, :delta, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
        97.970  END;
```

In this case, the average latency was increased by almost 5% (553.454 ms). This percentile varies from test to test, but latency is always higher when using Proxy.

What is the reason for this to happen? Is it just latency from an additional hop on the network? Is the processing time due to connection pool management? Did I miss something in the tests?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try asking Amazon support? Also, isn't the difference in the "initial connection time" bothering you more?

Comment: Obviously injecting yet another processing step is going to introduce some latency.  5% seems entirely unremarkable.  Was there a point to this exercise?  What is remarkable is that you want to have 600 simultaneous connections to one m6i.large instance.